# How to turn particles in circular shape

Tags: particles

I want to rotate my particles in circular (cyclone) fashion. I want my particles to be in lines shape and not sphere. I tried to add Bezier curve converted to mesh and applied as particles. But its not having the turn effect. How can i achieve this type of effect. Any suggestion or help. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is shift+a go-to curve/circle. Then add an object to the scene.
give that object a particle system and leave it all at default other than the object
[image]
[image]

then select the circle and go-to Physics and add forcefield

[image]

change the type to curve guide

[image]

you should be good! If you assigned the object with the particle system to itself you just need to duplicate it. Moving the particle emitting object will change the orbit size around the circle.

This is what it looks like (as a png sequence)
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: as i have mention in my question i need a curve line or curve mesh not a cube as particles

Comment: just assign the particle object in the particle system to curve line object as seen in the first image next to dupli object.

Comment: in my question i have assign my curve lines hope you have seen but the particles direction is same and i want in circular or cyclone type

Comment: I have attach my file. Plz go through. Thanks

Comment: so you want a tornado like thing

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6377" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6377/)

Comment: In the force field shape how u get 3 (curve, plane, point). I do not have curve option.

Comment: whats your blender version?

Comment: old version 2.79b

Comment: if you have a different type of force field selected it changes the amount of those things in the middle. Look at the 3rd and 4th images